# Custom method implementation in Spring Data fails with property not found error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to implement custom method in Spring Data repository using Spring Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE.
I created the repository:

```
package com.example.springdatademo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, String>, CustomMyEntityRepository {

}
```

Provided the custom repository:

```
package com.example.springdatademo;

interface CustomMyEntityRepository {
    MyEntity myCustomFindQuery();
}
```

And the implementation:

```
package com.example.springdatademo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    class CustomMyEntityRepositoryImpl implements CustomMyEntityRepository {


        @Override
        public MyEntity myCustomFindQuery() {
            System.out.println("hello from custom query implementation");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Plus, I provided an invocation:

```
package com.example.springdatademo;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@EntityScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringDataDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDataDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner run(MyEntityRepository repository) {
        return (args) -> {
            final MyEntity myEntity1 = repository.myCustomFindQuery();
            repository.save(new MyEntity(1, "fieldTwo"));
            for (MyEntity myEntity : repository.findAll()) {
                System.out.println(myEntity);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

`pom.xml` is just plain one generated from spring initializer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
<!--        <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>-->
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-data-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When running the project on Spring Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE I'm getting a problem on container creation:
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query method public abstract com.example.springdatademo.MyEntity com.example.springdatademo.CustomMyEntityRepository.myCustomFindQuery()! No property myCustomFindQuery found for type MyEntity!`

Changing the Spring Boot version to 2.1.9.RELEASE works fine and gives me the expected result.

I can't find any tips in [spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.11.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations)

Comment: I guess the interface should be named `MyEntityRepositoryCustom `

Comment: according to the documentation it doesn't matter as long as there is an `Impl` postfix. This is just a quick reproducible examle

Comment: can put it on github

Comment: May be you are looking into new docs. You have to check docs pertaining to the spring data version you are using. But give my suggestion a try. Also make sure all the three files are in same package, repository, customrepository and impl

Comment: @pvpkiran renaming didn't help. Also, the link I've provided refers to the actual version of the documentation used in code.

Comment: @Shailesh https://github.com/s-kramer/spring-data-problem-reproduction

Comment: I have fixed the code. Do check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just checked out your code and was able to fix it. This is what I did

Rename `MyEntityRepositoryCustomImpl` to `MyEntityRepositoryImpl` and

As I told you in my comment, cutom repository should be named `MyEntityRepositoryCustom`(I guess you already did this)

Naming convention is the key here. Impl class should be named `<BaseRepository>Impl`. And not `<CustomRepository>Impl`

Comment: ahhhh I see now - the implementation must have the name of the base repository, not the custom repository.

Comment: although it's weird that you can have only 1 extension class per repository

Answer (score 0):

If you want your current code to run then you need a `@NamedQuery` if you want to run hql
or if you want to run native query `@NamedNativeQuery` with a name `MyEntity.myCustomFindQuery` in your Entity class

```
@NamedQuery(name="MyEntity.myCustomFindQuery", 
query="SELECT 1 as a, 'a' as b from MyEntity")
```

or

```
  @NamedNativeQuery(name="MyEntity.myCustomFindQuery", 
    query="SELECT 1 as a, 'a' as b", resultSetMapping="mapmyCustomFindQuery")

@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "mapmyCustomFindQuery", classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(targetClass = MyEntity.class, columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "a"), @ColumnResult(name = "b")
                
        })
})
```

**Alternatively you can keep both repositories separate (means `MyEntityRepository` shouldn't extend `MyEntityRepositoryCustom`**

in that case, your Application class will look like below

```
@Autowired 
    MyEntityRepository repository;
    
    @Autowired
    MyEntityRepositoryCustom entityRepositoryCustom;
    
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDataDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner run() {
        return (args) -> {
            final MyEntity myEntity1 = entityRepositoryCustom.myCustomFindQuery();
            repository.save(new MyEntity(1, "fieldTwo"));
            for (MyEntity myEntity : repository.findAll()) {
                System.out.println(myEntity);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to use the `@NamedQuery` approach - I want to extend the Spring Data repository

Comment: then I would suggest keeping custom repository separate becuase @Repository
interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, String>, MyEntityRepositoryCustom  will try to resolve action on all methods defined

Comment: this is the suggested way of extending the Spring Data repositories, as described in the documentation

Comment: could you please add the url of  documentation

Comment: it's in the original quesion: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.11.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations